# Can CatBoost be installed in a Conda environment?

Tags: python, conda, catboost

Does Yandex support Anaconda environments? I'm trying to get CatBoost working in PyCharm using an Anaconda environment as Python interpreter, but I continue to get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catboost'. I'm able to install CatBoost using pip, but not with 'conda install', and especially not 'conda install' with an -n flag specifying a particular conda environment.﻿

Comment: i see Catboost spelled with both a capital c and a small c in your question. Python is case sensitive. Are you sure you tried importing it with correct spelling?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using anaconda and just pip installed it.

Any particular reason you need it installed by Conda?

Answer (score 1):

`conda install -c conda-forge catboost`